# What is the probability that when a deck of cards is shuffled and dealt, exactly 3 of the 4 aces will be dealt within the last 20 cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to figure out this problem, I think that it is a "permutations with repetition" type of question.

Comment: "Permutations with repetition" usually means you can have as many copies of each thing as you like, as long as the total number of things is the desired number. So one of the permutations of 20 playing cards with repetition is a hand containing 19 aces of spades and one king of hearts (for example). That's not what  you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like all of the "poker probability" questions, you may reword this as asking about the probability of a twenty-card hand satisfying the condition that it contains exactly three aces.

- Determine a useful sample space, preferably one which is equiprobable (*one in which all outcomes are equally likely to occur*).

  > I recommend using the sample space $S=\{\text{all ways to draw twenty cards ignoring order in which they are drawn}\}$, or equivalently worded $S=\{\text{all twenty-card hands}\}$
- Determine the size of the sample space

  > $\binom{52}{20}$
- Describe the desired event that we wish to find the probability of with regards to the sample space

  > Exactly three aces occur in the twenty card hand.  In other words, three aces and seventeen non-aces will occur in the hand.
- Count in how many ways the event occurs

  > Pick which aces are used and pick which non-aces are used.  Apply multiplication principle of counting.
- Apply definition of probability in an equiprobable sample space:  $Pr(E)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about order of the aces, nor identity of the other cards.   This is all about *placement* in the deck.

In general, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select $k$ places from $n$.

---

You have 4 aces and 52 places to put them in the deck.   Count the ways to select 4 of 52 places as the measure of the total space.

For the favoured space we need 3 of the last 20 places, and 1 of the first 32 places.   Count the ways to so select them.

Divide and calculate.